# Test run command without executing it but showing result of command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Some time ago I learned a command that would run the command and show the end result, but it wouldn't actually execute the command, just the outcome as if it was ran. I forgot this command and can't seem to find it on the web. Do you happen to know the command that's needed? Your help is greatly appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop with GNOME. Setup:

- Intel i9700
- GSkill Trident 16 GB RAM
- Nvidia RTX 2080
- Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD

The command I'm looking for is a general terminal command used by different distros. I have used it on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 before (and maybe Fedora, don't remember which version).

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Can you give a specific example? I don't think it's possible *in general* - it's often not possible to determine the outcome of a command without running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The command I'm looking for is a general terminal command

I assume we refer to a bash command of some sort, since bash is the default interpreter of Ubuntu's terminal.

From my understanding, you are looking for an option similar to `-whatif` in microsoft powershell (if you're familiar with it), that lets you execute almost every known command, but without changing anything, thus letting you know if your syntax is correct, or the outcome of a chain of commands.

Unfortunately, such feature does not exist (and I really wish if we had one).

So what you are actually referring to is a set of options and flags many "commands" have, that will simulate your parameters. Those "commands" are usually a set of scripts or aliases to scripts that are also capable to simulate your parameters, and not a pure core os command.

The most common flags are: `--dry-run`, `--simulate` and `--fake`, which many program scripts usually offer them. But the keyword here is "**usually**", as without a built in feature and piece of code in the script by the author it just won't work.
Here is an example of APT: `sudo apt-get install --dry-run "the_package_i_really_want"`.

From apt-get manual page:

```
-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.
Configuration Item: APT::Get::Simulate.
Simulate prints out a series of lines, each one representing an rpm
operation: Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square brackets indicate broken packages with an empty set of square brackets meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare).
```

Here is another example of the `mount` command:

```
sudo mount --fake /dev/sda1 mydir
```

From mount manual page:

```
-f, --fake
  Causes everything to be done except for the actual system call;
  if it's  not  obvious,  this  ``fakes'' mounting  the  filesystem.
  This option is useful in conjunction with the -v flag to determine
  what the mount command is trying to do.
```

There are some external tools / scripts and tricks that people wrote and you may try, but that also might be risky and up to your research now.

Comment: Hi Pizza, thanks for your reply. I'll try the --simulate and --dry-run commands. Since I am still a beginner, is 'Commands' the right name to use for typing stuff in terminal (Bash)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: We usually refer to any line we write in the command line as a "command", but sometimes (like my answer to this thread) we should remember that it is not always this way. As you continue with your linux experience, you'll soon understand that many commands you are using are actually programs or scripts provided with the OS. APT for example, is a package manager software that comes with Ubuntu and Debian based OS. It will not work in many other linux OS, thus at first it seems to us like it's just a terminal command, but it's actually not. The option `--dry-run` for it is a built in option.

Comment: To conclude: that is the reason some "commands" have some kind of a simulation option, and some do not. Overall bash (and many other) interpreters don't have some general command simulation option, but if they do have - those options were added by the developer. To know if your command has such option, you can always view the manual page for this command using `man` `your command name`.

Comment: Since I can't find the DM function on askubuntu.com I want to thank Pizza for helping me. Thanks Pizza.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure such a command exists since some commands would likely ruin a system if run on bare metal, such as "rm -rf / --no-preserve-root". If the command could be destructive, then just spin a Virtual Machine and test the command there.